# Android TV - having a multiple headers using VerticalGridSupportFragment

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I've a design, where I have to have multiple headers while using `VerticalGridSupportFragment`. I know, that headers can be easily added if you use ListRow, where you just pass in headerItem and adapter, but if not mistaken, then that is not a possibility for VGS Fragment.

How can I achieve this? Maybe small example?

The data I have:

```
BIG-OBJ:
    title: "1"
    list-of-small-objs: small1, small2, small3
BIG-OBJ2:
    title: "2"
    list-of-small-objs: small1, small2, small3
...
```

Image of the idea:

[image]

So I want to display headerItem as `BIG-OBJ.title` and it's content as `BIG-OBJ.list-of-small-objs`.

1. Can this be done using VGS Fragment?
2. Small example of the same idea would be great.

Comment: Hi. Did you figure this out?

Comment: If you have already figured this out, please add your answer, so others can get benefitted. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`VerticalGridSupportFragment` is for creating leanback vertical grids that renders a **vertical grid of objects** given a [VerticalGridPresenter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/VerticalGridPresenter) and an [ObjectAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ObjectAdapter).

I think you can use [`HeadersSupportFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/HeadersSupportFragment) that contains a list of row headers.

You can check the [code](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=kingargyle/adt-leanback-support/adt-leanback-support-master/leanback-v17/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/app/HeadersSupportFragment.java) from this blog post.